# Getting output socket name and using it for input socket name in compositor

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, compositing-nodes

i'm trying to do an automated naming system for my file outputs in blender compositor, i want the file output input's socket to get the name of the input of their respective links. I'm not really getting how (new in python). So far my script looks like

```
import bpy
import os

# Get absolute path:
filepath = bpy.context.scene.render.filepath
absolutepath = bpy.path.abspath(filepath)

# Split it
path = os.path.normpath(absolutepath)
parts = path.split(os.sep)

absolutepath = os.sep.join(parts[:-2])

# Get name of th input
name01 = bpy.data.node_groups["CYCLES MULTIPASS CREATION"].outputs[0].name

# set the path for all file output nodes:
for scene in bpy.data.scenes:
    for node in scene.node_tree.nodes:

        if node.type == 'OUTPUT_FILE':
            node.base_path = absolutepath
            node.file_slots[0].path = "\_shadow\_" + "nom" + "_" + name01
```

But this is "absolute" version of what i'm trying to do, the input socket name is not relative to the output socket name of the previous node... Somebody has an idea ? thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the name of the socket a node's input is linked to:

```
#using the File output node from your example
link = node.inputs[0].links[0] #gets the link from the input
socket_name = link.from_socket.name #returns the name of the socket the link is from
```

Comment: thanks man ! it works, but i have to input the socket number ( [0] ) every time, is it possible to just tell blender to get the right one, depending on the output one ?

Comment: I don't quite understand.

Comment: i mean is it possible to just put something like `link = node.inputs.links[0]` without an imput number to get something applyable to all the input immediatly ?

Comment: inputs is a list of inputs so you have to designate which one, even if there's only one.

Comment: ok i see, the only inconvenient is to not be able to use a file output node with multiple input, not a real problem thank you very much for your quick answer !

Comment: You could, if you designate it by name instead of by index. You would just have to know the name of the input i.e. inputs['Some Input']

Comment: yep right, do you know how i could change a node name by python ? (sorry maybe i have to ask that in a separate question...)

Comment: found it ! `simplenode = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeOutputFile')
    simplenode.name = "Composite Output"`